# How to push item in a list in Realtime Database with serial indexing like array?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to push an item to a list (`joinedGrps`) every time a user creates a group, but when I try to push any item to the list, the value set to an automatically generated id

[image]

But I want it to store like an array with indexing starts with 0 like the below example

[image]

**CODE**

```
const RDBuserRef = realDB.ref(`users/${userInfo.userId}/joinedGrps`);
const newRDBref = RDBuserRef.push(grpName).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
```

So is it possible to do?

Alternatives methods are welcomed but it should be in Realtime Database

Comment: Trying to use sequential numerical indexes on the Realtime Database is an anti-pattern. I recommend reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) to learn why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#set) method instead of the [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#push) one, which "generates a unique key every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference".

In order to know which key to use, you need to first read the Array, add a new element and then, write it back.

The following will do the trick:

```
  const groupRef = realDB.ref(`users/${userInfo.userId}/joinedGrps`);

  groupRef
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const grpArray = snapshot.val();
        grpArray.push('...');
        groupRef.set(grpArray);
      } else {
        groupRef.set({ 0: 'Elem#1' });
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

**HOWEVER**, if several users are able to update the database node you need to use a [`transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#transaction). Since you need to read the array before writing it back, using a transaction is the only way to ensure that there are no conflicts with other users writing to the same location at the same time.

```
   groupRef.transaction(currentArray => {
      if (currentArray === null) {
        return { 0: 'Elem#1' };
      } else {
        currentArray.push('....');
        return currentArray;
      }
    }
```

Comment: hey i did something like this ```RDBuserRef.set([...userInfo.joinedGrps, grpName]).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });``` , it is efficient

Comment: userInfo is the previously fetched data of the `joinedGrps`